# Ubuntu or Fedora for a C++, Java, Python and Ruby developer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, linux-distro

I use the above languages to develop web and desktop applications. I am currently using Ubuntu 11.04 and a friend is urging me to switch to Fedora. What benefits will I get in doing so?

Comment: Sorry, this ain't constructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. Make your friend give you the reasons to switch.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934430/fedora-vs-ubuntu-for-software-development-pros-cons

A few helpful links

- http://www.diffen.com/difference/Fedora_vs_Ubuntu
- http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1aqorr/times_they_are_achangin_ubuntu_and_fedora_are/
- http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/280324/ubuntu-vs-fedora-
- http://www.xenstreet.com/2013/02/ubuntu-vs-fedora/